# Occupied litter box stalking

Tags: cats, behavior, training

Our new cat Dizzy, stalks either of our cats when they are in the litter box. Then said cats dart out of the box to escape. Any suggestions about how we resolve this?

We have two hooded litter boxes and we recently put out a litter tray.
One hooded box is upstairs and the other two are downstairs (one around the corner from the other).  Dizzy uses the tray and I believe at least one hooded box.

Whereas the other cats Woody and Dot only use the hooded boxes.

Comment: Are the boxes in separate places, or all next to each other/in the same room?

Comment: Ones upstairs, one downstairs and the open own is round the corner from the other downstairs one

Comment: [The conventional advice seems to be to have one litterbox per cat plus one more.](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/as-a-complete-novice-what-costs-should-i-plan-for-when-adopting-a-shelter-cat/1559#1559) you have 3 cats and 3 litter boxes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how that would cause the stalking, does it mean it's a territory thing, your in my toilet? Dizzy will stalk at both hooded litter boxes.

Comment: More likely it's just a "you're cornered and distracted" moment. I also quibble with the N+1 litter box suggestion; this _really_ depends on how your cats interact. (I keep telling my two "hey, do I supervise when _you_ visit the litter box?" Doesn't help, they still insist on joining me.)

Answer (score 1):

Providing a clear and easy escape path might help with this. That can be as easy as removing the hoods from the other boxes.